# How to select only the last row for an inner join?

Tags: sqlite

I know this question was asked many times, but i haven't understood this fully and need some help.
I have following Sqlite Database:

```
Liste
id | Name
------------
1  | Paul
2  | Logan

Theory
id | RefID | file
-----------------
1  | 1     | file1
2  | 1     | file2
3  | 2     | file7
4  | 2     | file3
5  | 1     | file4

    SELECT l.id, l.Name, t.file 
    FROM Liste l 
    INNER JOIN Theory t on l.id = t.RefID 
    GROUP BY l.id;

Results:
1 | Paul  | file1
2 | Logan | file7

expected result:
1 | Paul  | file4
2 | Logan | file3
```

could anyone give me a hint on how to get 
the last added row?

Regards Sascha

EDIT:
Well I don't know why, but a nested inner join works somehow.

```
    SELECT l.id, l.Name, t.file 
    FROM Liste l 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Theory ORDER BY Theory.id asc) 
    t on l.id = t.RefID 
    GROUP BY l.id;
```

Comment: So you *only* want the row `2 | Logan | file7` to be returned?

Comment: Sorry should have made this more clear, I added expected results in my main post.
I read so much about different ways to do this, but some of them do not work for me, and I don't understand the other :D

Answer (score 0):

To select the rows with the largest `id` value in the group, use `max()`:

```
SELECT max(l.id), l.Name, t.file
FROM Liste l
JOIN Theory t ON l.id = t.RefID
GROUP BY l.id;
```

Comment: But I Need the largest id from Table Theory, and when I tried that, I had the largest id, but not the associated file, ;(

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Comment: SQLite3 module version 
7.0.22-3 
SQLite Library 
3.21.0